# how to display absent or present result

Tags: php, mysql

how to display absent or present result

please help me to fix this issue thanks

now showing like this result

```
________________________________________
 Name   TeacherNo   Attendance
________________________________________
 XYZ       993             5 Days Present

 Abc       991             7 Days Present

 123       955             2 Days Present

________________________________________
```

and i want like this

```
________________________________________________________________
Name    TeacherNo      Present Day          Absent Days
_________________________________________________________________
XYZ       993             5 Days Present        3 Days Present

Abc       991             7 Days Present        0 Days Present

123       955             2 Days Present        4 Days Present  

________________________________________________________________
```

This is code

```
 $result1 = mysql_query("select name ,id ,`teacherno` as teacherno, CONCAT(count(`teacherno`),' Present days') as Attendance
   from tattendance 
   where `Attendance` = 'present' AND date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-07' group by `teacherno` order by attendance desc");
```

Comment: pls share a tab delimitated result-set. Hard to understand this result. And how absent days are calculated? Is it also fetched from DB??

Comment: What is the magical purpose of this `'teacherno' as teacherno`?

Comment: teacherno is like teacherid all teacher have separate id to view result becz some time teacher name are same thats why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the following query:

```
SELECT name, teacherno, 
    CONCAT(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Attendance = 'present' THEN 1 END),0),' Present days') as Present,
    CONCAT(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Attendance = 'absent' THEN 1 END),0),' Absent days') as Absent
FROM tattendance  
GROUP BY teacherno
```

This usese `SUM` with `CASE` to add up the days depending on the Attendance column.  I also included `COALESCE` to return 0 instead of `NULL`.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb6a6/1)

Comment: this is my tables  how can i echo present and absent table                echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['teacherno'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['Attendance'] . ' and this is present table now</td>';
  echo '<td>here absenet table i want</td>';

Comment: @user2260431 -- np, was editing including a sample, but sounds like you got it.  Best regards.